# transition duration how can I put it when I click a buttom thats display a menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to put like a slow transition duration to the menu from top to bottom when the menu appears when you click the grey circle.

How can I put timing to this effect???

https://jsfiddle.net/sp78wu0o/20/

```
<nav class="dropdown">

<div onclick="myFunction()" class="start-button dropbtn"></div>

<div id="myDropdown" class="nav-list dropdown-content">
 <a href="" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
 <a href="" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
 <a href="" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
 <a href="" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
 <a href="" class="nav-items">HOME</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You can add a css transition effect as you can see here on the link bellow where I have also correct some of your javascript and html code.
https://jsfiddle.net/sp78wu0o/62/

```
<ul id="myDropdown" class="nav-list dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-items">HOME</a></li>
</ul>

.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#myDropdown {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: .2s all ease;
}

#myDropdown li {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.show {
  top: 130px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David it was really helpful  you did a great job.